# Unable to Pass Form Data in Ajax POST

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, razor

I am trying to submit form data through an Ajax call on a razor page. However I am having issues creating the FormData to put into the Ajax call.

Here is the form

```
<form id="dropdownForm" asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Statements" method="post">
<input type="text" id="startInput" name="start" hidden />
<input type="text" id="endInput" name="end" hidden />
<div class="form-group">
    <p>Choose an account</p>
    <select id="AccountDropdown" select class="selectpicker" data-size="10" data-live-search="true" asp-for="@Model.SelectedAccounts" multiple data-actions-box="true" data-style="btn-white" style="right:0; left:auto;">
        @foreach (var item in Model.AccountDropdown)
        {
            if (Model.SelectedAccounts.Any(e => e.AccountValue == item.AccountValue))
            {
                <option value="@item.AccountValue" selected>@item.AccountName (@item.AccountCode)</option>
            }
            else
            {
                <option value="@item.AccountValue">@item.AccountName (@item.AccountCode)</option>
            }
        }
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <button id="accountSubmit" value="Update Selection" class="btn btn-primary">Update Selection</button>
</div>
```

I have a separate button on the page that I want to submit this form to a different controller action.

What I have done is.

```
let myForm = document.getElementById('dropdownForm');
let formData = new FormData(myForm);

$.ajax({
async: false,
cache: false,
//contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
contentType: false,
type: 'POST',
data : formData,
url: '/Statements/GetStatementData',
success: function (data) {
    tableData = data.StatementsList;
},
error: function (e) {

    Console.log(e);

}
});
```

The variable myForm is being pulled correctly and it has all of the values and information I need in it. But the FormData object is empty, and it fails on the Ajax call internally.

Here is a screenshot of the objects right after I declare `formData`

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: **Do not use async:false**.  Not only was it removed in jQuery 3X, browsers themselves are deprecating it.

Comment: Post your controller action. The issue is probably there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change from `let formData = new FormData(myForm);` to `myForm.serialize()`

Also you should put name for AccountDropdown.

Note: **Your name of input tag in form must same with property name in your model for Model Binding correctly.**

```
let myForm = $('#dropdownForm');
//let formData = new FormData(myForm);

$.ajax({
async: false,
cache: false,
//contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
//contentType: false,
type: 'POST',
data : myForm.serialize(),
url: '/Statements/GetStatementData',
success: function (data) {
    tableData = data.StatementsList;
},
error: function (e) {

    Console.log(e);

}
});
```

Update:

```js
let myForm = $('#dropdownForm');
let data = myForm.serialize();
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="dropdownForm" asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Statements" method="post">
<input type="text" id="startInput" value="1" name="start" hidden />
<input type="text" id="endInput" value="2" name="end" hidden />
<select id="AccountDropdown" name="account">
   <option value="A1">A1</option>
</select>
</form>
```

I make a demo for serialize()

Comment: I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: myForm.serialize is not a function`

Comment: did you try let myForm = $('#dropdownForm'); ?

Comment: That looks better, I'm having issues on the controller side though. Do you need to model bind the post data in the controller or is just having string parameters ok?

Comment: you only need set name of input tag same with property name in model

Comment: thats what I thought, here is the action `public async Task<IActionResult> GetStatementData(string start, string end, string accountValue)` but start is null when i see it in the serialized data.

Comment: Disregard that, needed to remove ContentType. Thanks!